# LibreOffice problem when trying change details

Tags: linux, libreoffice

Am long term user of LibreOffice

When open cells to modify details on the **change page** it opens longer down than shows on my monitor(s).

LibreOffice has similar results with both ubuntu and openSUSE.

How can we **change page**  to **re-set size** (eg 80% size) to ensure depth, width (?) fits the page, or scroll down, so can read all **change page**   ?

## - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

My LibreOffice:
Version: 7.6.2.1 (X86_64) / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 60(Build:1)
CPU threads: 4; OS: Linux 5.14; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3
Locale: en-AU (en_US.UTF-8); UI: en-US
Calc: threaded

## - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

I was using libreoffice-calc

Usually no problems with the ***modfiy details page***

Only libreoffice warning found today, these usually show when re-start computer:

gnome-shell[1976]: Warning: Hiding app because parental controls not yet initialised: libreoffice-startcenter.desktop

gnome-shell[1976]: Warning: Hiding app because parental controls not yet initialised: org.gnome.Calculator.desktop

Just ran updates and **zypper ps -s** shows **soffice.bin** as one of my updated/deleted files, so need log out.

.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce the described behavior. Can you specify: LibreOffice/Calc (? judging on the _cells_); the **change page** is in which menu/submenu (? Format/Page Style);

Comment: "_Just ran updates and zypper ps -s shows soffice.bin as one of my updated/deleted files, so need log out._" - did this mean you don't need your question any more?

Comment: Suspect the "modfiy details page"  needs be modified or able to limit size used so it displays no more than 80% of the screen, so can scroll down the details page.


Am switching between computers and Os's, the screen sizes differ, also some OS's use part of screen for short-cuts.


Am needing to go away for a while :-(